# change the names in angularjs program is not taken into account

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

Hello I'm working on a maven project with springboot and angularjs
When I changed the name of my controllers and templates (js and html files ) the request URL is not the new but the old one and I got this error :

`Request URL:http://localhost:8080/name_of_the_old_controller.js Request Method: GET Status Code: 404  Remote Address: [::1]:8080 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`

Thank you for your help in advance,

BTW i'm new in angularjs :-)

Comment: Please provide us with your codebase structure

Comment: Have you searched the project for any references to `name_of_the_old_controller.js`? If none exist, you may have either a compilation or caching error